# Group and chop vector layer by attributes

Tags: qgis

Im new to QGIS but i have a layer which contains buildings.
What i want to do is to chop up that layer into groups of buildings.
So if you imagine a town with 5000 buildings, i want to create new layers each containing 50 buildings only.
I can extract attributes, but dont know how to iterate over the entire layer pulling out buildings 50 at a time to create effectively a grid or polygon with 50 houses each time.
Help :)

Comment: Could you maybe also explain what you want to achieve with this exercise? What would be the benefit to have 100 different layers? This is quite against the principles how to best store and handle data.

Comment: I might have articulated it badly. What I am trying to achieve is to group things together in such a way that i can filter them out to export individually. So for example, take a town with 500 houses. I would like to cluster them in groups of 50 to create an individual map of that sub area. Does that make sense? It doesnt need to be layers, but needs to be done in such a way that I can take a town and create sub areas based on number of houses

Comment: well, than create a new field in your attribute table, name it group, select your clusters of houses and give them an identical ID. Then you are able to filter the dataset by this group ID. As none know how you want to group them, there is no meaningful way to automatically assign such an ID to every 50 houses, this is what you have to do by yourself.